# What datatype should i use for saving the unique user id returned by an Oauth provider

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, userid

I want to store the unique user id returned in the response by an Oauth provider in my SQL database. I've seen some posts suggesting that varchar(128) should be enough. Are there any providers whose user id extends this limit? I have checked the docs for some of the more popular providers like Google, Facebook and Github but I can't seem to find any information about the size of this user id.

Answer (score 1):

[OIDC defines the `sub` claim as](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken):

> A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client, e.g., 24400320 or AItOawmwtWwcT0k51BayewNvutrJUqsvl6qs7A4. **It MUST NOT exceed 255 ASCII characters in length. The sub value is a case sensitive string.**

So better use VARCHAR(255).